# Create a web service client in Hybris

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, sap-commerce-cloud, webservices-client

Im new in Hybris and I need to build a web service client that consumes a web service rest.

Someone have an example? or something that give me an idea, I dont know if is the same like build a web service client in spring.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For REST you can use the default Spring framework for rest client. See this tutorial. [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) You can create a new extension or use one of yours. See below for more info.

I used Apache Axis2 for consuming the WSDL (the web service). There are a lot of examples and tutorials on the internet for this. It can easily be integrated in Hybris.

- The clearest solution is to create another extension using **extgen**
  . Some tips [here](https://help.hybris.com/6.6.0/hcd/8b96270b86691014b1c3bbfd7556f0ed.html) . You have to modify other the
  extensioninfo.xml file of the other extension, where you want to use
  the client. (more info in the link above).
- The easiest solution is to just add the axis2 lib to the extension
  you want to handle the client and use it there. If you want to play
  around and test it as a prove of concept, you can do that. Later you
  can move it to a separate extension.

Comment: There are another way to consume a Rest service without the Axis2 Lib or any lib?

Comment: Aaa sorry i missed the REST part. Axis2 won't be useful in your case. For rest you can check the default Spring techniques. I will update my answer for that.